# Problem converting and calculating time difference in minutes

Tags: delphi

I'm using `'hh:mm am/pm'` in my `TDBEdit` box.  I want to convert this string to time, then calculate the difference in minutes, and convert this back to a string to place in the next edit box so that its value will be automatically calculated.

```
procedure TfrmActivity.edEndExit(Sender: TObject);
var
  s, e : TTime;
begin
  s := StrToTime(edStart.Text);
  e := StrToTime(edEnd.Text);
  edTotTime.Text  := FloatToStr(MinutesBetween(e,s));
end;
```

But, I keep getting an error `invalid time format '8::0 M'`.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why don't you use [TDateTimePicker](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker) or [TTimePicker](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.WinXPickers.TTimePicker) instead or regular `TEdit` components? That way you don't have to be doing any conversion from string to time since mentioned components already store their value as TDateTime by default. Also [MinutesBetween](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.DateUtils.MinutesBetween) returns result as Int64 and not as Floating Point value.

Comment: Using an overloaded StrToTime with a specific `FormatSettings` record will in most cases solve any problems. See https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrToTime

Comment: Converting (free-format) string to datetime, and doing math on this, potentially involves a long list of checks and validation. Are dates valid ? Is the exact string pattern respected ? Is start less than / equal to end ? How do you handle potential timespan from 11:58 pm --> 01:04 am ? Can a timespan be more than 24 hr ?  Have you checked if your function has locale settings in play ? Etc etc. I would say that just calling `StrToTime()` is inviting problems.

Comment: @SilverWarior, I tried this OnEnter     edTotTime.Text  :=  IntToStr(MinutesBetween(TimePicker2.Time, Timepicker1.Time));  but it just gives answer off by 1 minute.  What should be adjusted?

Comment: Time is actually correct, it's my smartwatch that entered the wrong times.  So @SilverWarior is my accepted answer.  How to make this the answer?

Comment: Just to let you know that minutes aren't formatted as `mm` but rather `nn`. `mm` is used for months. http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.php?Name=formatdatetime

Comment: _Time is actually correct, it's my smartwatch that entered the wrong times_ How is your smartwatch entering these times? Also I noticed you are mentioning `TDBEdit` Are you storing these values in database? If so why don't you use SQL query to calculate time difference between the two fields. YOu can use [TIMEDIFF()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_timediff.asp) function for this.

Comment: @SilverWarior, yes I'm using SQLite.  Didn't know about TIMEDIFF().  May use that instead as I can't seem to get the two DBEdits to store the correct times from the TimePickers into the table.  Always put some arbitrary time close to the end time, but in both DBEdits.  So, thanks for all your help, I will explore using TIMEDIFF() instead.

Comment: @SilverWarior, yes I'm using SQLite.  Didn't know about TIMEDIFF().  I am using the data from my Smartwatch workout and manually entering the data from those two fields.  There is no desktop app, so I created my own and hopefully will port to mobile one day.

Comment: There can also be a minute's difference if seconds are not taken into account. MinutesBetween(a, b) will round down to the nearest minute (e.g. a difference of 1 minute and 59 seconds will calculate a difference of 1 minute). I generally use Round(MinuteSpan(a, b)) which does take seconds into account and will round up or down as appropriate.